# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Subscriptions are not supported with the CustomProvider

Tags: truffle

Trying to deploy the newly created contract into rinkeby test network but got struck with the below error. Please check the code, error message and package.json details below.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const {interface, bytecode} = require('./compile');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
'frog almost employ roast protect host citizen festival rural alone document misery',
'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/560e70f3ebfc4f628a53f4143b9460fd'
);
const web3= new Web3(provider);
const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts =  await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    try {
        const contractDeployment = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: '0x'+ bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there! I am inside Rinkeby'] })
        .send({from: accounts[0] });
console.log(contractDeployment.options.address);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

};
deploy();
======================================================================
Error:
(node:58876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Subscriptions are not supported with the CustomProvider.
    at CustomProvider.subscribe (C:\BlockChain\node_modules\web3-providers\dist\web3-providers.cjs.js:1139:13)
    at NewHeadsSubscription.subscribe (C:\BlockChain\node_modules\web3-core-subscriptions\dist\web3-core-subscriptions.cjs.js:52:43)
    at NewHeadsWatcher.watch (C:\BlockChain\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:180:110)
    at C:\BlockChain\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:50:31
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:58876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:58876) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
=======================================================================
Package.Json
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.2.3",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.25",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.6",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
```

Comment: Infura only supports events through websockets endpoints.

Comment: @Ismael  I tried to replace the provider to 
provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/560e70f3ebfc4f628a53f4143b9460fd');    But I am not now even able to fetch account for deploying the contract. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like this known issue with beta.48: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2462

Maybe try downgrading web3.js to beta.37, that seems to be the most stable option at the moment.

Comment: I already have the beta.37 version